# Probability of picking one card without another one.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, card-games

I'm having some troubles understanding a probability question.

In a game, there 21 assets and we pick 5 of them.

Let the events : 
A = "pick the first asset" 
B = "pick the last asset"

We are ask to find p = P("A or B")

I've said that "A or B" = "A and B" + "A without B" + "B without A"

So first I can compute P("A and B ") = nCr(2,2)*nCr(19,3)/nCr(21,5)
where nCr(n,k) represents 'n choose k'. This part is correct yet.

But I don't understand why the probability to pick one card without the other one isn't given by : P("A without B") = nCr(2,1)*nCr(19,4)/nCr(21,5)

In the correction, the resolution goes another way : 
it says that "A or B" = A + B - "A & B", and then compute P(A) = P(B) 
I understood why that was correct, but I cannot understand where my mistake is and I would appreciate very much some help here.

Thank you,

Arthur

Comment: Please write in MathJax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: I have not seen $nCr(2,1)$ as the number of ways to choose $1$ item from $2$.  Most common here is $2 \choose 1$, which you get by putting 2 \choose 1 in dollar signs.  Closer to what you use is $_2C_1$ which you get by putting _2C_1 in dollar signs.  I have used your notation.

Answer (score 2):

For pick one without the other, the $nCr(2,1)$ is the number of ways to choose one of the two and the $nCr(19,4)$ is the number of ways to choose four cards from the remaining $19$.  This will give the number of ways to get exactly one of A or B.  If you want A without B you should change the $nCr(2,1)$ to $nCr(1,1)$ because you are only selecting from A for the first card.